# They had a better understanding of A than (they had) (an understanding) of B

Tags: comparative-constructions, comparative

> a. But earlier on, American intelligence officials said they often had a better understanding of Russia's military plans than of Ukraine's. (Source: [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/09/10/us/politics/ukraine-military-intelligence.html))

Is it possible to use these alternatives to mean the same thing? Or are these impossible constructions?

b. But earlier on, American intelligence officials said they often had a better understanding of Russia's military plans than **an understanding** of Ukraine's.

c. But earlier on, American intelligence officials said they often had a better understanding of Russia's military plans than **they had an understanding** of Ukraine's.

Comment: Researchers understand thale cress better than they understand other plants.

Comment: They are not 'impossible', but most native speakers would find them unnecessarily repetitive. _They had a better understanding of A than they did of B_ would be acceptable.

Comment: @KateBunting Here's an argument for saying it's impossible: How can you possibly add "an understanding" when the comparative form "better" resides inside the NP _a better understanding of Russia's military plans_? Regarding _They had a better understanding of A than they did of B_, how about _They had a better understanding of A than they had of B_.

Comment: Yes, you could use _had_ instead of _did_.